# How to take screenshot of a Facebook post + All children and grandchildren comments?

Tags: screenshot, facebook

Is there a tool or way to automatically take screenshot of entire expanded comment chain of a Facebook post?

Currently I need to manually scroll and expand all children comments one by one.

Comment: How are you viewing FaceTweet? Windows? Android? Something else? Are you willing to pay,. or do you seek a cost free (grais0 solution? The more info you give us, the better we can help you. Welcome aboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Mozilla Firefox add-on, [Capture & Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/capture-print/), that can effectively scroll a page to capture its full extent. You might need to manually expand each comment to get this to work - untested.

Answer (score 0):

How are you viewing FaceTweet? Windows? Android? Something else? Here's a Widnwos solution:

For over a decade now, I have been using [FastStone Capture](https://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm). It more than meets all of my needs, and can certainly do what you are asking.

You have to pay now, and it is probably worth it, but the [last free version](https://whatsonmypc.blog/2009/05/14/faststone/) is still excellent and meets your needs.

[image]

> 1. Capture Active Window
> 2. Capture Window /Object
> 3. Capture Rectangle Region
> 4. Capture Freehand Region
> 5. Capture Full Screen
> 6. **Capture Scrolling Window**

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer for the part about automatically expanding comments, however to take the screenshot of an entire very long Facebook post with all comments the best method I found is via [Print Edit WE add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit-we/) on Firefox. I expand comments manually as usually it's not too long to do; although that might take a lot of effort for you, depending on your use case.

Print Edit WE is a well-known add-on and not a big privacy risk contrary to some other alternatives solutions.

1. launch Print Edit WE from the Facebook single-post window
2. select the post title and text box-containers, then find the big box-container that contains all comments; you might need to hover the mouse around a bit near the edges of the comments area until you see the proper box-container highlighted (often there are multiple containers built one inside the others, not just on Facebook but on most modern web pages)
3. use the Delete Except button on the left-side of the Print Edit WE toolbar ; I typically use Restricted or Unrestricted depending what works best for my use case
4. if necessary to improve the layout and/or text flow, use the Fix Page Breaks function under the Tools button on the right-side of the Print Edit WE toolbar
5. save or print

Other methods I tried that didn't work :

- the built-in Firefox screenshot tool ; to get all comments on a Facebook post it opens in its own sub-window, and the full-page option in the Firefox screenshot tool doesn't work on those
- Microsoft PowerToys Crop & Lock ; it can't deal properly with the single post sub-window in the browser
- the full-page screenshot in Apple Safari on iOS ; the Safari version of Facebook cannot show all comments on a single page